# Magento 2.1 : How to create dynamic custom header link without using cacheable = false

Tags: magento-2.1, cache, full-page-cache, header, holepunching

The cacheable = false works fine, but fpc gets completely disabled and pages are too slow.

Here is the default.xml

```
<referenceContainer name="header.panel">
    <block class="Custom\Mod\Block\Account\SponsorHeader" name="float.sponsor"  template="account/sponsor.phtml" >
        <arguments>
           <argument name="css_class" xsi:type="string">header links</argument>
         </arguments>
    </block>
</referenceContainer>
```

Is there any other way without using cacheable = false ?